# How to instantiate an instance of a Ruby class when the class changes dynamically?

Tags: ruby

So I am trying to create a text game in ruby, and I have attempted to create a `fight` method that can deal with creating any object. I have a `Monsters` class in another file, and child classes such as `Rogue` and `Vampire`. I have managed to make this work by using a `case` statement that instantiates an object named `m` that is either `Rogue` or `Vampire`, and putting practically all the methods in the `Monsters` class so that they share the same method name, but is there a more efficient way of dealing with unknown objects?

My code:

```
def fight(monsterToFight) 
case monsterToFight
when "Rogue"
  m = ::Rogue.new
when "Vampire"
  m = ::Vampire.new
else
  puts "error 503"
end
... #more code
```

link to full repo: https://github.com/chaseWilliams/textGame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-const_get).

```
class_name = "Rogue"

rogue_class = Object.const_get(class_name) # => Rogue

my_rogue = rogue_class.new # => #<Rogue ...>
```

In your example, this would look like:

```
def fight(name_of_monster_to_fight)
  monster_class = Object.const_get(name_of_monster_to_fight)
  m = monster_class.new

  # ... more code

rescue NameError # This is the error thrown when the class doesn't exist
  puts "error 503"
end
```